# how to integrate powerbi dashboard in ios application swift

Tags: swift

javascript SDK Integration 
how to html file in the asset xcode

Java Script SDk

var models = window["powerbi-client"].models;

```
var embedConfiguration = {
    type;: "report",
    id: '5dac7a4a-4452-46b3-99f6-a25915e0fe55',
    embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: 'h4...rf',
    settings: {
            layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait
        }
};
```